# How do I know what button was clicked? (Unity)

Tags: c#, gui, events, unity

I have a prefabbed button (UI.Button) which I'm instantiating ten times:

```
public void LayoutButtons() {

    GameObject newCanvas = Instantiate (canvas) as GameObject;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        buttons[i] = Instantiate(button, new Vector2((i * 100.0F)-500, -100), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        buttons[i].transform.SetParent(newCanvas.transform, false);
        buttons[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "Button " + i;
    }
}
```

However, I'm now stuck when trying to figure out which button was clicked. The Unity `onClick` seems to only allow zero or one parameters. I've tried using `public void onClick(Button button)` with `button.getComponentInChildren<Text>().text` but I get `ArgumentException: failed to convert parameters`

*All I want to do is print out the clicked button's text. How can I do this?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the built-in `onClick` in the Editor, make your own and add the listener yourself.

```
public void PrintText(string buttonText) {
    Debug.Log("Clicked " + buttonText);
}
```

Add a listener in to your `LayoutButtons` function (you don't need to keep track of the buttons using the array so just use `tmp` or something):

```
tmp.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener( () => { PrintText(tmp.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text); });
```